# Adding multiple accounts for "You do not have permission to modify this app" error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-launch

I have two google app engine accounts. One for business and one for personal.

In my GoogleAppEngineLauncher, I have a mix of these app engines on the same computer.

Whenever I want to deploy these apps, I have to go into the terminal and remove my auth tokens using `rm ~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens` and then have the browser pop-up and re-sign into my appropriate account.

Is there a way to have multiple tokens so if one doesn't work, it'll try the next so I don't have to keep deleting my tokens and re-signing in?

Would love to have both my accounts listed so I can deploy either of them without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy managing multiple accounts with the [gcloud tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#windows)'s [auth command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/).

Once installed and set up, you can authenticate with:

```
gcloud auth login
```

This can be repeated multiple times for your various accounts.

To see all accounts that have been set up:

```
gcloud auth list
```

To select a particuluar account:

```
gcloud config set account ''ACCOUNT''
```

Comment: GoogleAppEngineLauncher does not use `gcloud` it uses `appcfg.py`. I've tried this before and it doesn't work :\